# Creating a view function that charges the card using the already successfully created token with stripe.js

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I'm using stripe elements from the official documentation to create a token. Now I'm trying to build a charge function in my view.py to charge the credit card. But how do I properly get the token from stripe.js in my views.js because "request.POST.get('stripeToken'):" doesn't work in my code.

I'm trying to set up a user sign up form in django where the user needs to pay a single fee when he signs up (not saving the token for recurring payments). I'm now trying to build a charge function in my views.py which charges the card with the already successfully created token. The reason why I want to use stripe elements with stripe.js is the good looking form.
I am relatively new to this environment and because of that I don't know how to go on. 
Thanks for your help already in advance!

```
views.py

import stripe

def charge(request):
    # Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
    # See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
    stripe.api_key = "sk_test_..."

    # Token is created using Checkout or Elements!
    # Get the payment token ID submitted by the form:
    if request.POST.get('stripeToken'):
        print(request.POST)
        token = request.POST.get('stripeToken')

        charge = stripe.Charge.create(
            amount=999,
            currency='usd',
            description='Boosted Post',
            source=token,
        )
        print('Charge:', charge)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        print('NO')

    context = {
        'amount': 999,
    }

    return render(request, 'subscribers/subscriber_new.html', context)


subscriber_new.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  {% load static %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/stripe.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
  <form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <label>
      <div id="card-element" class="field is-empty"></div>
      <span><span>Credit or debit card</span></span>
    </label>
    <button type="submit">Pay $25</button>
    <div class="outcome">
      <div class="error" role="alert"></div>
      <div class="success">
        Success! Your Stripe token is <span class="token"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/stripe.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>


stripe.js

var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_...');
var elements = stripe.elements();

var card = elements.create('card', {
  iconStyle: 'solid',
  style: {
    base: {
      iconColor: '#8898AA',
      color: 'white',
      lineHeight: '36px',
      fontWeight: 300,
      fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
      fontSize: '19px',

      '::placeholder': {
        color: '#8898AA',
      },
    },
    invalid: {
      iconColor: '#e85746',
      color: '#e85746',
    }
  },
  classes: {
    focus: 'is-focused',
    empty: 'is-empty',
  },
});
card.mount('#card-element');

var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input.field');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('focus', function() {
    input.classList.add('is-focused');
  });
  input.addEventListener('blur', function() {
    input.classList.remove('is-focused');
  });
  input.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    if (input.value.length === 0) {
      input.classList.add('is-empty');
    } else {
      input.classList.remove('is-empty');
    }
  });
});

function setOutcome(result) {
  var successElement = document.querySelector('.success');
  var errorElement = document.querySelector('.error');
  successElement.classList.remove('visible');
  errorElement.classList.remove('visible');

  if (result.token) {
    // Use the token to create a charge or a customer
    // https://stripe.com/docs/charges
    successElement.querySelector('.token').textContent = result.token.id;
    successElement.classList.add('visible');
  } else if (result.error) {
    errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    errorElement.classList.add('visible');
  }
}

card.on('change', function(event) {
  setOutcome(event);
});

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = document.querySelector('form');
  stripe.createToken(card).then(setOutcome);
});
```

After the token is already created successfully and is also visible in the dashboard of stripe, the charge function should get the token and charge the  card successfully.
But in reality the console directly shows the printed 'No' and the browser instantly redirects to the home.html page without even showing the subscriber_new.html file which could before successfully generate a token without the charge function in the views.py file

Comment: Can you post the contents of js/stripe.js as well? Could be an issue where you aren't mounting Stripe Elements correctly.

Comment: I added the stripe.js file and thanks for your answer.

Comment: Are you sure your form is submitting correctly? I can't see where or how your frontend sends the Stripe token to your backend in `setOutcome`.

Comment: Yeah, the line `Use the token to create a charge or a customer` is a placeholder, you need to write code there to submit the token to your backend server.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. @Paul Asjes I think this is my problem but I don't know how to send the Stripe token to my backend because setOutcome is from the official documentation. Thanks Karllekko I didn't know that but do I have to locate the charge function at this point? I thought the charge function should be located in the views.py file because in the official documentation exists a example charge function written in python.